# How to handle error exceptions on a procedure that has 2 inputs and 2 outputs?

Tags: java, api, exception, error-handling, dao

Hi i'm fairly new to java. This week I worked on an endpoint that deletes.In order to delete I pass a ID & sequence number but the procedure i'm calling on the DAO takes four paramters which are ("OutStatus")&("OutStatusMsg") so I end up passing id,sequenceNumber, NULL, NULL. I got told, I need to handle the outstatus and outstatusMsg. I am not sure how to handle this kind of exceptions. Please help.. very lost since i'm new.

```
final Integer statusCode = (Integer) ("OutStatus");
            final String statusMessage = (String) 
("OutStatusMessage");



            if(DB_STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS != statusCode)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        statusMessage);
            }
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new ApplicationException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    ErrorMessage.DATABASE_ERROR.params(), e);
        }

private final String Store_Incident_PROCEDURE = "call Store_PROCESS_PKG.DELETE_Store_incidents_P (?, ?, ?, ?)";


    public void deleteStoreIncidents(final List<InputStoreMessage> inputStoreMessages) {

        ArrayList<Object[]> batchArgs = new ArrayList<>();

        inputStoreMessages.forEach(inputStoreMessage ->
                batchArgs.add(new Object[]{inputStoreMessage.getStoreId(),inputStoreMessage.getIncidentSequence(),null, null})
        );

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(Store_incident_PROCEDURE, batchArgs);
    }
```

Comment: *I got told* - Then ask that person - no?

Comment: OK, where is the exception thrown?  and what type is the Exception ?  Also, if you simply handle the exception, does the delete still work? If not, it does not seem like a good solution.

Comment: right now, I do not have  a exception just the top part but that was just me putting an example of what I think the exception should look like. Currently when I run my API through postman I am able to delete records and I know this because I have checked on the database. But on teh acutal postcall I only get a 204 NO CONTENT, even though it deleted the record /not